# Export used materials to Excel/csv

Tags: export, asset-browser

Is there a way to export a "picking list" based on a model?

For example I create a building, in this model I use saved assets, like bricks, wooden beams,....
Now I want to export this to a list that says "100 bricks", "20 wooden beams".

I think that it can be done with the asset browser.

I'm new and can't find an answer. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: The asset browser is still under development. What you are asking might be possible using python but there's no built-in way of doing what you want at the moment.

Comment: This would be easy to do using Python, since one could write a loop that outputs the list as a CSV file; but there's one tricky bit: determining what is a 'brick'.  If you're willing to define a rule and stick to it, like 'all bricks, no matter what I call them, go into the brick collection' or 'all bricks have 'brick' in their name, then it would be easy, but you would have to follow the rule always.